# Python class and method description

Tags: python, documentation

How can I conveniently view class structure and methods description in python? I know about `help(method)` method, but it's not easy for use. F.e. I have download a library, and I know that it hase class Foo. I wanna see methods and meaning, have I to look for documentation or other way exists?

Comment: Perhaps look over the source code.

Comment: Use a different IDE? In Pycharm I do find it helpful that I can <key>CTRL</KEY>-click on a class/function def or call and it opens the source code, which is helpful when the documentation is a little lackluster or unreadable

Comment: Doesn't help you avoid downloading a library to understand it, but if you download it (assuming the library is named foo) and do import foo; dir(foo) from a python shell, that will return the list of things in foo (including Foo).  If you have some vague notion you want to do something with bar, something like for i in dir(foo): if i.lower().find("bar") != -1: print i  will return all things in foo that contain bar (or BAR or Bar or ...) [but pydoc as in the answer or better IDE also work]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pydoc` in the form `$ pydoc <name_of_library>[.<name_of_module>[.<name_of_function>]]`. To get information about `requests`'s `Reponse` object, for example, you would do `$ pydoc requests.models.Response`.

`pydoc` is installed in any standard Python distribution.

Comment: Also, full documentation can be avalible by command python `pydoc.py -b`